# my listview and my button are not clickable in my fragment

Tags: android

I have a `fragment` that contains a `ListView` and a `button`.
The `fragment` opens with the items in the list but neither the items are clickable nor the `button`.
I tried to add
    `android:clickable="true"` & `android:focusable="true"`   but it still not working

This is my xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"

    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"

     >

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/fragment_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
       />


    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/list_fiche"
        android:layout_width="399dp"
        android:layout_height="215dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.219"


        />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnaffiche"

        android:layout_width="227dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="132dp"
        android:background="@drawable/button"
        android:text="Afficher toutes les fiches"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/list_fiche" />


</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

and this is my class

```html
public class ListFicheActivity extends Fragment {
    List<FichePatient> fiches , firstfiche;
    android.widget.ListView ListView;
    FichePatient fiche ;
    Button btnaffiche, btnback;
    String ID;
    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       return inflater.inflate(R.layout.liste_fiches, container, false);
    }
    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(@NonNull View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
        Bundle b = this.getArguments();
        if (b != null)
            ID = b.getString("ID");
        ListView = getView().findViewById(R.id.list_fiche);
        btnaffiche= getActivity().findViewById(R.id.btnaffiche);
        getAllFiche();
        ListView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                Intent intent=new Intent(getActivity().getApplicationContext(),BottomNavigationActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra("idFiche",fiches.get(position).getId());
                intent.putExtra("age",fiches.get(position).getAge());
                intent.putExtra("idpat",Integer.toString(fiches.get(position).getIdPatient()));               startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
        btnaffiche.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent1= new Intent(getActivity().getApplicationContext(),ListFichePatientActivity.class);
                intent1.putExtra("ID",ID);
                startActivity(intent1);
 } });}
    void getAllFiche() {
        Bundle b = this.getArguments();
        if (b != null)
            ID = b.getString("ID");
        IFiche iFiche= APIClient.getClient().create(IFiche.class);
        iFiche.getAllFiche(Integer.parseInt(ID)).enqueue(new Callback<List<FichePatient>>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<List<FichePatient>> call, Response<List<FichePatient>> response) {
                Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(),"Succefully connected to Database",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                Log.v("!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!", Integer.toString(response.body().size()));
                fiches=response.body();

                for(int i=fiches.size()-2; i>=0 ;i--)
                {
                    fiches.remove(i);
                }
                Log.v("taille!!!!!", Integer.toString(fiches.size()));
                AdapterFiche userAddapterFiche = new AdapterFiche(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), fiches);
                ListView.setAdapter(userAddapterFiche);
            }
            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<List<FichePatient>> call, Throwable t) {Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(),"error",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                Log.v("tag",t.getMessage());
            } }); }}
```

Comment: Where did you define in java the `button` and `listview` because what I see there aren't defined both of them.

Comment: i didn't put all the code , i update it now check it .

Comment: @ImenElAbed , please post the complete code of fragment .

Comment: @ImenElAbed I have edited little  it your code show changed when you define `ListView` and `Button` copy that code and tell me what is showing.

Comment: @Spritzig i put all the code now

Comment: @ImenElAbed Check for changes at your code I have made, when you declare the `ListView` and the `Button`.
Make those changes at your code and tell me if that works.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you should name your ListView object as *listView* instead *ListView*. Try to get reference to your objects using `view.findViewById(R.id.list_fiche)` instead of `getView().findViewById(R.id.list_fiche)`.

Also, you should use [RecyclerView](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/recyclerview) instead of ListView.

Answer (score 0):

Everything when you define it need to be related with the id which you have declared at the `xml`.
For example you define a `Button` at `xml` you cannot write in `java` only

```
Button.setOnClickListener
```

But you need to define that `Button` with which id of the button is related like this.
For `Fragments`

```
Button myButton = view.findViewById(R.id.yourXmlID);
```

For `Activites`

```
Button myButton = findViewById(R.id.yourXmlID)
```

You need to define `ListView` and `Button` something like this.

```
ListView listView = view.findViewById(R.id.list_fiche);
Button btnaffiche= view.findViewById(R.id.btnaffiche);
```

And for the click listeners something like this.

```
public class ListFicheActivity extends Fragment {
    View paramView;
    ListView listView;
    Button btnFiche;
    String ID;
    FichePatient fiche;

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        paramView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.liste_fiches, container, false);
         listView = paramView.findViewById(R.id.list_fiche);
         btnFiche = paramView.findViewById(R.id.btnaffiche);
        Bundle b = this.getArguments();
        if (b != null)
            ID = b.getString("ID");

        getAllFiche();

        listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                Intent intent= new Intent(getActivity(), BottomNavigationActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra("idFiche",fiches.get(position).getId());
                intent.putExtra("age",fiches.get(position).getAge());
                intent.putExtra("idpat",Integer.toString(fiches.get(position).getIdPatient()));
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });

        btnFiche.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent1= new Intent(getActivity().getApplicationContext(),ListFichePatientActivity.class);
                intent1.putExtra("ID",ID);
                startActivity(intent1);
            }
        });
        return paramView;
    }

    public void getAllFiche() {
        Bundle b = this.getArguments();
        if (b != null)
            ID = b.getString("ID");
        IFiche iFiche= APIClient.getClient().create(IFiche.class);
        iFiche.getAllFiche(Integer.parseInt(ID)).enqueue(new Callback<List<FichePatient>>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<List<FichePatient>> call, Response<List<FichePatient>> response) {

                Integer.toString(response.body().size()));
                fiches=response.body();

                for(int i=fiches.size()-2; i>=0 ;i--)
                {
                    fiches.remove(i);
                }

                AdapterFiche userAddapterFiche = new AdapterFiche(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), fiches);
                ListView.setAdapter(userAddapterFiche);
            }
            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<List<FichePatient>> call, Throwable t) {Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(),"error",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                Log.v("tag",t.getMessage());
            } });
    }
}
```

Comment: This should work, @Spiitzig You should also explain your answer a bit, it would help OP understand the mistakes.

Comment: @humble_wolf Thank you for the tips but I was surprised how he defined `ListView` and `Button`.
I prefer always to use the `RecyclerView`.

Comment: You should not be surprised, clearly he is new to programming, try to make him understand the mistakes otherwise he will make them again.

Comment: Try to create a `Log` at the button `.
btnaffiche.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
Log.d("IsClicked", "Clicked");
           } });`

And tell me if you see this message at the `LogCat`

Comment: when i change getView() by view the previous fragment appears on my current gragment and it still non clickable

Comment: @ImenElAbed Why you have both of them `onCreateView` and `onViewCreated` it is the same fragment or not, because if it is you need to put all your code at the `onCreateView`.

Comment: when i put all the code at the `onCreateView`    `view.getfindViewById()` is not working and tell me that Cannot resolde symbol view

Comment: thank you very much, i have 3 hours searching a solution and i didn't found it

Comment: @ImenElAbed I am creating a project to look like yours and I will add here as answer. I will write when I edit my answer.

Comment: @ImenElAbed I have edited my answer show for the code please.

Comment: thank you for your effort but the problem still the same and the last fragment appears as background of the current one

Comment: But you said it is the same fragment. How do you open this fragment can you add that?